# UV and haze lens for Canon Powershot SX50 HS

Tags: lens, filters, adapter, powershot

Looking for UV and CPL lens for this camera. As far as I am aware the supplied lens is 58 mm. Offers seem to have either 58 mm lens sets from Fotover etc.  or 67 mm lens form Neewer etc. I assume for the latter the adapter enables the kit to work (i.e. fit 67mm to 58mm). I would like to check before purchase.

Answer (score 2):

The threads on the Canon PowerShot SX50 HS are non-standard and designed to only take the [Canon Filter Adapter FA-DC67A](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/filter-adapter-fa-dc67a), which attaches to the threads on the SX50 HS and then provides standard 67mm threads for whatever 67mm filter one wishes to use. There are also [third party versions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BGYW8FP) of the FA-DC67A that do the same thing: allow 67mm filters to be attached to the adapter which is attached to the camera.

There have also been third party adapters offered by Lensmate and [others](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013QUE2ZE) reputed to fit the threads on the PowerShot SX50 HS that will then allow filters with 58mm threads to be used.

Answer (score 1):

As far as official support, page 35 of the [SX50 HS manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300008700/01/pssx50hs-cug-en.pdf) states that 67mm filters will work with the camera in conjunction with the FA-DC67A filter adapter. I would assume this adapter only works with 67mm filters. It appears that 3rd party equivalents of this adapter that state 67mm also only work with 67mm filters.

The 3rd party adapters that allow 58mm filters only work with 58mm filters.